# Not Able to Connect Prod OIM

Tags: java, weblogic11g, oim

I have a code that actually able to connect to Lab OIM but same code i am not able to connect to Prod OIM. Below is the code i am using. Did i miss anything? I have all those Jars also in my Project build path. Help and any suggestion will be appreciated. Below are the code and error i am getting after debugging the class.

```
 public class ConnectionTest {
         UserManager userManager;

          public ConnectionTest() {
                  super();
                }
   public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException, Exception {

    ConnectionTest oim=new ConnectionTest();
    oim.OIMConnection();
}
 public void OIMConnection(){             
    Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    env.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_FACTORY_INITIAL, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_PROVIDER_URL, "t3://hostname:port");
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\Documents\\authwl.conf");
    System.setProperty("OIM.AppServerType", "wls");  
    System.setProperty("APPSERVER_TYPE", "wls");
    oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient oimClient = new oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient(env);

    try {                        
        oimClient.login("username", "password".toCharArray());         
        logger.info("Successfully Connected with OIM!\n");
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        CharArrayWriter cw = new CharArrayWriter();
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(cw);
        e.printStackTrace(w);
        logger.error("Login Exception: "+ cw.toString());
    }            
    userManager = oimClient.getService(UserManager.class);
}}
```

Error I am getting is here.....

Login Exception: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: weblogic.socket.UnrecoverableConnectException: [Login failed for an unknown reason:  P] at weblogic.security.auth.login.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
    at Thor.API.Security.LoginHandler.weblogicLoginHandler.login(weblogicLoginHandler.java:61)
    at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.login(OIMClient.java:212)
    at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.login(OIMClient.java:196)
    at org.com.dis.exa.ConnectionTest.OIMConnection(ConnectionTest.java:73)
    at org.com.dis.exa.ConnectionTest.main(ConnectionTest.java:53)

Comment: You're using the code above? Have you hide the connection for us? Did you configure the jndi.properties? Do you have conectivity for production enviroment of your machine?

Comment: This is probably a yes,  but have you checked to make sure you are not trying to connect to prod using your test credentials?

or have you replaced the "username" and "password" with the correct users credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check username and password.
2. Get wlfullclient.jar from Prod(not Lab).
3. Check C:\Documents\authwl.conf. It is Prod's file?

refer my sample:

```
public static final String OIM_HOSTNAME = "oim.hpt.lab";
public static final String OIM_PORT = "14000";
public static final String OIM_PROVIDER_URL = "t3://"+ OIM_HOSTNAME + ":" + OIM_PORT;
public static final String OIM_USERNAME = "tungpt";
public static final String OIM_PASSWORD = "Hpt123456";
public static final String OIM_CLIENT_HOME = "F:/designconsole11gr3/config";
public static final String AUTHWL_PATH = OIM_CLIENT_HOME + "/authwl.conf";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OIMClient oimClient = null;
    try {
        //Set system properties required for OIMClient
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", AUTHWL_PATH);
        System.setProperty("APPSERVER_TYPE", "wls");

        // Create an instance of OIMClient with OIM environment information  
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_FACTORY_INITIAL, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_PROVIDER_URL, OIM_PROVIDER_URL);
        oimClient = new OIMClient(env);

        // Login to OIM with the approriate credentials
        System.out.println("Login by: "+ OIM_USERNAME);
        oimClient.login(OIM_USERNAME, OIM_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Login Done!");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```